# TravisCI: No pypi deployment after new tag

Tags: deployment, travis-ci, pypi

I have added a new tag and pushed my changes. On TravisCI I can see this:

```
$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl
12.44s
dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
Logged in as Yves Chevallier
Deploying to repo: heig-vd-tin/sphinx-heigvd-theme
Current tag is: 0.5.1
dpl.3
Deploying application
Setting target_commitish to 74778b3e2c67d53feac20af148afdc2e1672f7c2
```

My deploymement configuration is the following:

```
deploy:
  - provider: releases
    api_key:
      secure: aQfM0IIsFSvqk...VLdaAc=
    skip_cleanup: true
    file_glob: true
    file: ./dist/*
    on:
      tags: true
  - provider: pypi
    user: my-pypi-username
    distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
    password:
      secure: K0XYNnK6FV+YqeeUDsZ1SYbtj9w....MYS8tLw=
    on:
      tags: true
```

But, I nothing have been committed to PyPi.

How to debug this?

Comment: You should be able to "open" the `Deploying application` line to reveal multiple log lines relating to the deployment. Can you include them here as well?

Comment: This is the opened version :(